# how to do python word replacement?

Tags: python, regex, string, replace

I want to replace some **word** from string. for eg. 'eq' to '=', 'gt' to '>'

take an example such as this:

```
s = "name eq 'alex' and age gt 36" to "name = 'alex' and age > 36"
```

I can not use string.replace() since it replace on character.
Should I split the sentence and then `re.sub(r'^eq$', '=', s)`? Is there an easy way to do this?

ps. I don't want to do `s.replace(' eq ', ' = ')` since there may be word at start or end of string. For example, replace me to 'alex' in `sender eq me` should result in `sender = 'alex'`

Comment: "*can not use string.replace() since it replace on character*"  <-- huh?

Comment: I am not quite sure of the reason why you do not want to use string.replace(). It seems to be the perfect solution for what you want to achieve

Comment: He probably means he doesn't want something like `equity` to become `=uity`

Comment: exactly @flakes

Comment: if `eq`, `gt` and `lt` are expressed in separate words, there is no problem of using `string.replace`.

Comment: @bulbus I imagine cases like this: `a eq b`, `eqe eq b`, `'a'eq b`, `(a)eq b`. you're correct though. A question needs a good set of expected input vs outputs; especially when you ask a question with many corner cases.

Comment: @flakes I agree with you that regex questions can have many corner cases.

Comment: @bulbus eg. replace me to 'alex'. eg. `sender eq me` to `sender = 'alex'`

Comment: @bulbus the OP says "I don't want to do s.replace(' eq ', ' = ') since there may be word at start or end of string" I assume that means its not always white-space delimited. Expected output then is  `a eq b`, `eqe = b`, `'a'= b`, `(a)= b`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use regex to replace. It will avoid the misleading effects.

```
import re

s = ("name eq 'alex' and age > 36 equity eq\n"
    "{ dictionary: \"\" } eq { dictionary: \"\" }\n"
    "\"string\" eq \"string\"\n"
    "var eq var\n"
    "[\"list\"] eq [\"list\"]\n"
    "(\"tuple\") eq (\"tuple\")")

regex_template_start = r"(?<=[' \"\w\[\]\(\)\{\}])\b"
regex_template_end   = r"\b(?=[' \"\w\[\]\(\)\{\}])"

s = re.sub(r"{0}{1}{2}".format(regex_template_start, "eq", regex_template_end), '=', s)
s = re.sub(r"{0}{1}{2}".format(regex_template_start, "gt", regex_template_end), '>', s)

print(s)
```

View the result: https://repl.it/MLpM/5

---

**Explanation:**

> Python Variable Rules Variables names must start with a letter or an
>   underscore, such as:
>
> - _underscore
> - underscore_
>
> The remainder of your variable name may consist of letters, numbers
>   and underscores.
>
> - password1
> - n00b
> - un_der_scores

So the regex must cover the variable name cases.
In addition, it can be a tuple, a dictionary or a list, so the regex includes`[]{}()` as well.

Comment: can you explain a bit?

Comment: @Mengo lookup "lookarounds"! https://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html

Comment: @bulbus I'd probably just go with `(?<=[^0-9a-zA-Z_])eq(?=[^0-9a-zA-Z_])`

Comment: I think you can discuss this in the chat section, comments are not a good way.

Answer (score 1):

Seems that `replace` is the perfect solution.

```
s = "name eq 'alex' and age > 36" 
goal = "name = 'alex' and age > 36"
s = s.replace(" eq ", " = ")

s == goal
```

Comment: If operators can be on the edge of your string as well you could check the start and end explicitly rather than operate on the entire string.

Answer (score 0):

Here we are using `REGEX` to achieve desired output.

**Regex:** `(?:(?<=^)|(?<=\s))eq(?=\s|$)`

1. This will match `eq` and positive look behind for either `start of string ^` or `space \s` and positive look ahead for either `end of string $` or `space \s`

**Solution 1:**

[**Regex demo**](https://regex101.com/r/GpxTC9/1/)

```
import re
s = "name eq 'alex' and age > 36"
print re.sub('(?:(?<=^)|(?<=\s))eq(?=\s|$)',"=",s)
print re.sub('(?:(?<=^)|(?<=\s))gt(?=\s|$)',">",s)
```

[**Try this code snippet here**](https://eval.in/874839)

**Solution 2:**

You can do it like this replacing `space-eq-space` to  `space-=-space`

As per requirement you have in question `eq` has `space` after and before `eq`

[**Try this code snippet here**](https://eval.in/874812)

```
s = "name eq 'alex' and age > 36"
print s.replace(" eq "," = ").replace(" gt ", " > ")
```

Comment: In the comment, the OP says why the method is not what is wanted, because it can modify other instances of 'eg' or 'gt' like say for example in 'equity', as pointed by @flakes

Comment: I do not know what is the reason of down voting this elegant solution either! It seems to be better solution than the others. In the end of the chain `.replace(" lt ", " < ") ` can be added though.

Comment: @SanyamMehra On SO we should add answers which will be helpful to everyone having such pattern problems , rather then just looking on a specific case.

Comment: @SanyamMehra When a thing can be done with an elegant way with inbuit function then, Why should we move for a complicated way with `REGEX` Thats my opinion Else its upto you .. :)

Comment: Please refer to the question:

"ps. I don't want to do s.replace(' eq ', ' = ') since there may be word at start or end of string."

What you are suggesting does not satisfy what the OP wants.

Comment: Also, even using regular expression, the programmer will anyway have to program the replacements required, which is the same as the if statements in a way. Moreover, for `N` words and `M` replacements, the `for` loop solution is `O(N * M)`, which is not too bad.

Comment: @SanyamMehra Might be that was my bad, I have also added a Regex solution you can check that one.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a simple for loop to avoid changing other instances of 'eq' and 'gt'

```
# split on space character
words = s.split(' ')    

# loop and check every word
for i, w in enumerate(words):    

    # replace occurrence of r'^eq$'
    if w == 'eq':    
        words[i] = '='

    # replace occurrence of r'^gt$'
    elif w == 'gt':     
        words[i] = '>'

s = ' '.join(words)
```

Comment: remove the unnecessary spaces between lines.

Answer (score 0):

just use the **re.sub** function

```
import re
s = "name eq 'alex' with equity gt 36"
s = re.sub(r'\s{1}eq\s{1}', ' = ', s)
s = re.sub(r'\s{1}gt\s{1}', ' > ', s)
print(s)
```

the output is **name = 'alex' with equity > 36** exactly what you want

Answer (score 0):

One solution can be creating a dictionary with `key:value` of all the values which needs to be replaced.
Splitting the string into a list solves the problem with words like

```
equity
```

which also contain the word `eq`

```
dicta = {
    "eq" : "=",
    "gt" : ">",
    "lt" : "<"
}
```

I have tried replacing the words from list which are in dictionary. It doesn't work perfect, but another way to do this task. I am trying to update it.

```
s = "name eq 'alex' and age gt 36"
[s.replace(char, dicta.get(char)) for char in s.split(" ") if char in dicta ]
```